How to picture $x^n−y^n \equiv (x−y)(x^{n−1}+x^{n−2}y+\cdots+xy^{n−2}+y^{n−1}) \; \color{red}{∀ \; n ≥ 4} \text{ ?}$
For $n=2, 3$, this identity can be visualized with differences of areas and volumes. But how can students pictorialize $x^n−y^n \equiv (x−y)(x^{n−1}+x^{n−2}y+\cdots+xy^{n−2}+y^{n−1})$  $\color{red}{∀ \; n ≥ 4} $ ?
This identity is Michael Spivak, Calculus (4 edn 2008), p. 13, Problem 1(v). But I found no picture proof in Roger B. Nelson's Proofs without Words (1993),
Proofs without Words II (2000), or Proofs without Words III (2015).

Why do you suppose that for any 5d r higher problem there should be a visual proof? This formula comes to students who can divide polynoms. So its nice to have a visual proof for high school. up to 3d.

The algebraic proofs are also much simpler than the visual proofs, even for $n=2, 3$.  The proof for $n=3$ does generalize to higher dimensions, but you have to be willing to decompose "hypercubes".  I played a bit with representing everything as a length and using similar triangles to construct the powers but it was a mess.  Also tried to think of a combinatorial interpretation, but subtraction is a bit of an issue for combinatorial species.

Maybe there's a generalised way as to how you the original $$\left(1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^{n-1}\right)(x-1) = x^n-1$$ is visualised?

I suggest that the fruitful way to visualize this is to let $h=x-y$, so we are looking at $(y+h)^n-y^n$. Let's warm up with $n=4$. Then by using the binomial expansion the identity is
$$(y+h)^4-y^4=h\bigl(4y^3+6hy^2+4h^2y+h^3\bigr)$$
The visualization is for the leading term $4y^3h$. When we increment the edge length of our four-dimensional cube from $y$ to $y+h$, then in each dimension we add a four-dimensional slab of volume $y^3h$. This part is very intuitive, or "visual." It is what we train students to see when we teach differential calculus: think of $h$ as being infinitesimal.
The remaining volume chunks corresponding to $h^2y^2$ and $h^3y$ are rather difficult to track down. You can start to "see" where they come from by learning about the tesseract.  It gets bewildering, but we can put our finger on that tiny four-dimensional corner of volume $h^4$!
In general, we have
$$(y+h)^n-y^n=nhy^{n-1}+\cdots+h^{n}.$$ Note how the term $ny^{n-1}h$ corresponds to the derivative $\frac{dy^n}{dy}$. So we still see how the increment $h$ in edge length adds a hyper-volume chunk $hy^{n-1}$ in each of the $n$ dimensions, and we still see our tiny corner with hyper-volume $h^n$.
Now let's turn our focus to the blocks corresponding to the other terms from the binomial expansion. For $n=3$ we can see them.
We have
$$(y+h)^3-y^3=h\bigl(3y^2+3hy+h^3\bigr).$$
We draw the following sequence of visuals:

The base block with edge length $y$
The base block with three blocks corresponding to the term $3y^2$. Note each of the three has a rectangular base $y\times y$, hence volume $3hy^2$
The base block with three blocks corresponding to the term $3hy$. Note each of the three has a rectangular base $h\times y$, hence volume $3h^2y$
The base block with the small corner block corresponding to the $h^3$ term
All blocks together, to give the cube with volume $(y+h)^3$






Now let's go back to the case $n=4$.  In the linked Wikipedia page for the tesseract, it is stated that at each vertex, 4 cubes, 6 squares, and 4 edges come together.  These correspond to the terms $4y^3h$, $6y^2h^2$, $4yh^3$ from the binomial expansion for $(y+h)^4$ But it is difficult for our brains to visualize how these fit together.
In the general case for the terms of the binomial expansion for $(y+h)^n$, we focus on the $n$ edges that come together at the vertex $(1,1,\ldots,1)$. We can pick $k$ of the edges in $C(n,k)$ ways, and form a block with $k$-volume being $y^k$. Incrementing the other $n-k$ edge lengths by $h$ gives us a block with $n$-dimensional volume $y^k h^{n-k}$. We cannot visualize how all $2^n$ of these blocks fit together with our visual sense associated with the eye, but we can use our combinatorial and algebraic senses to visualize.

Why does $h=x-y$ look so much like derivative now? eg $$(y+h)^4-y^4$$

We picture the proof with algebra. Algebra is the method for visualization of higher dimensional problems.

+1. I almost left a similar comment. I appreciate the effort of the other answers but it's hard not to notice the lack of any actual visuals.

@Thierry Thanks. I also appreciate the effort of trying to visualize this or that in higher dimensions, but it is not easy and more often than not it just gives some vague picture which really is unhelpful for real calculation. In contrast, algebra is more often than not what is needed to actually calculate the thing. Visualization past 3D is simply not natural. My brother told me a story once about the leading string theorists whose work is largely in 10 or more dimensions. They were asked if they could visualize higher dimensions, without exception they said no.

Any of the $(n-1)$-dimensional faces of a cube with side length $y$ in $n$-space has $(n-1)$-dimensional volume $y^{n-1}.$ If you move that face $x-y$ units by lengthening the one side that's orthogonal to that face by just that much, you add $(x-y)y^{n-1}$ to the volume. After that change, any of the faces orthogonal to that one has $(n-1)$-dimensional volume $xy^{n-2}.$ Now move that face by that same distance $x-y,$ and you add $(x-y)xy^{n-2}.$ Keep going in that way and you get all of the terms.

A reframing-answer: I myself do not see the higher-degree identities as being at all being geometric but ... as being easy applications of the binomial theorem (a central fact in mathematics for some centuries now, and those yet to come). The point being that sometimes (often?) "algebra" gives us an accounting system that transcends pictorial stuff (as appealing as the latter may be?). :)
... as in @JamesS.Cook's answer! :)

"In the higher dimensions you cannot see everything, so you must have something, some tool, to guess or formulate things. And the tool was algebra, unquestionably algebra."  Hironaka, p. 1013 in https://www.ams.org/notices/200509/fea-hironaka.pdf.
